# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. //new

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2jZc.jpg)

public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ToString());

```
    public int chkuser()
    {
        if (con.State.ToString() == "open")
            con.Close();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Task2_SignUp where UserName= '"+txtUName.Text+"'",con);
        con.Open();
        int flag = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        return flag;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(chkuser()==0)
        {
            if (con.State.ToString() == "open")
                con.Close();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Task2_SignUp (UserName,Password,Name) values (@UserName, @Password, @Name)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
            con.Open(); //ERROR SHOWING IN THIS LINE
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            lblSignUp.Text = "Registration Successfull";
            _blank();
        }
        else if(chkuser()>0)
        {
            lblSignUp.Text = "Username not available";
        }
    }
    public void _blank()
    {
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtUName.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = "";
    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

}

QUESTION : This is the error i am getting dont know why.. and suprprisingly this same code worked two weeks back but not working now.. please help me if possible.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a differance but I would use the following if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) instead of the current way you are checking to see if the connection is open

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The connection was not closed the connection's current state is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343236/the-connection-was-not-closed-the-connections-current-state-is-open)

Comment: No.. same issue.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved. it's a minor error. Instead of (con.State.ToString() == "Open") i wrote (con.State.ToString() == "open") ... means instead of Capital 'O' i wrote small 'o' .. hence this problem occured.. rest my code is abosultely fine. As a trainee developer i learned this thing. If there is any other trainee developer of dot net who just started like me then you must not hesitate.. Just remember about the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. Function `chkUser` has an issue.  If the `txtUName.Text` contains a single quote, it will throw an exception.  Best to re-code it to use a parameter.
2. Also, WHERE is the exception occurring?  Post a stack trace.
3. There's no need for `con.State.ToString() == "open"` when you could use `connection.State == ConnectionState.Open`.
4. We have no visibility as to whether your database has changed since 'two weeks ago', so you might start there.

Comment: 1) is this error connected to database? 2) problem occuring in Function Chkuser during second time run.. i cheked with breakpoint.. 3) i always use con.state.tostring()=="open" as taught by my trainer.. am still in training period.. will it be any issue ? :)