# Exception Handling in C# using try catch

Tags: c#, winforms, return, try-catch

I have 3 Methods, I am try catch for every method. If an error occur in Third method it goes to exception.

```
private void M1()
{  
   try
   {
     //some code
     //calling M2()
     //some code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
private void M2()
{  
   try
   {
     //some code
     //calling M3()
     //some code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
}
private void M3()
{  
   try
   {
     //some code
     //Error Occur
     //some code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
}
```

Now it goes directly to M1() method and shows Exception. And the another method is

```
private void M1()
{  
   try
   {
     //some code
     //calling M2()
     //some code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
private void M2()
{  
   try
   {
     //some code
     //calling M3()
     //some code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      return;
   }
}
private void M3()
{  
   try
   {
     //some code
     //Error Occur
     //some code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      return;
   }
}
```

After exception also it execute the code in M2() and in M1().

Which Program is best...,

Comment: First of all, don't catch an exception if you don't do anything with it. So this is bad practise: `catch(Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }`. If you want to keep the original stacktrace, you should at least use `throw` instead of `throw ex`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761216/c-throwing-custom-exception-best-practices

Comment: None of them. 1) Catching an exception only to re-throw it -> no point, 2) Message boxes in non-UI methods -> bad separation of logic and presentation.

Comment: Addendum: The reason why catching exceptions only to throw them again is bad practice, is because exception handling is **extremely** slow.

Comment: @Nolonar: Exception handling is only extremely slow in debug mode, in release mode it's just slow.

Comment: don't use throw ex, use only throw. Instead of catching and throwing exception directly catch  the exception in the main method (M1), that's better option.

Comment: I use throw it is good...,

Comment: which program is best in which **sense** ??

Comment: I am a Learner..,In Programmer Sense..,

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing good or bad design, only your scenario decided the best approach.

If you want to catch the error on M1 then don't write `Try .. catch` in M2 and M3.

If you want to handle the error in the function where error was raised then put the `Try .. catch` in same function.

Comment: While I don't really like to end up in a discussion here, I strongly disagree: There *is* such a thing as "bad design"!

Comment: If i have more more methods i want to know where the error is then what i want to do...

Comment: do you want this for logging/auditing purpose?

Comment: No sir, Just for learning how to use try catch

Comment: Error is catched in a function, if you want to minimize the impact of error or perform some other operation. the try and catch will suppress the error in the function where it raised.

Comment: for suppressing the error only we want to use try and catch..,

Comment: yes, you want to log error in files or minimize the damage due to this error.